# Rround DateTime to the closest half-hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a DateTime column I need to add a new column using the DateTime column and convert and round the minutes ( YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:00) format.

Example:

```
DateTime
2021-06-01 11:32:00.000
2021-06-01 12:55:00.000
2021-06-01 00:29:40.000

Expected Result:

DateTime-------------------------------Converted--------------
2021-06-01 11:32:00.000----------------2021-06-01 11:30:00.000
2021-06-01 12:55:00.000----------------2021-06-01 12:30:00.000
2021-06-01 01:29:40.000----------------2021-06-01 01:00:00.000
```

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. The real question seems to be how to round to half-hours

Comment: I must admit, the (original) title of the question, and what is *actually* being asked appear to be completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is the old `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` method:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,[DateTime])/30*30,0)
```